# Кто такая "бабайка"?

Tags: этимология

Маленьких детей родители пугают какой-то "бабайкой". А кто это вообще такая? Сказочный персонаж, нечисть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бабайка - не какая-то, а какой-то. Хотя и женский вариант не исключен, но прежде всего это производное от Бабай - ночной дух в славянской мифологии. Происхождение неясно. Возможно связано с баба - короткое полено, чурбан.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ можно найти в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9).

Баба́й/баба́йка (тат. бабай — дед, старик) — в славянском фольклоре ночной дух, воображаемое существо, упоминаемое родителями, чтобы запугать непослушных детей.

В частности, Википедия ссылается на Даля.

*В Толковом словаре живого великорусского языка В. И. Даля слово «баба, бабай» с пометой татарск. новорос. оренб. объясняется как «дед, дедушка, старик; иногда в значении детского пугала». Даль указывает, что в этом случае может использоваться вариант «бабайка» (то есть старуха)*